# How to add bullets to angular material list?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I wanted angular material list with bullets. I tried adding `list-style` / `list-style-type` css properties. But its not working.  How can achieve that?

[image]

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-83vv6f?file=app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 3):

I was also unable to get `display:list-items` & `list-style-type` to work... but looking at the documentation, we may have to use either:

- matListIcon
- icon library such as font-awesome

this is the block of HTML where you can have your choice:

```
<h3>Simple lists</h3>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of simpleItems">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>lens</mat-icon>
    <!-- OR -->
        <mat-icon matListIcon>fiber_manual_record</mat-icon>
    <!-- OR -->
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:16px"></i>
    <!-- OR -->
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:12px"></i>
        {{ item }}
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
```

forked [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-9mmnkw)

Comment: I have too big list with 500+ list items. So I wanted to define bullets in css once  instead of adding html block again and again for each item

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unicode character such as [this one](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2B24) as a bullet character.

The example of usage:

```
my-li:before {
    content: "\2B24";
    color: black;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

Comment: in Angular 12 this causes the "content" to show up on a different line.  Adding display: inline to my-li didn't help either.